# What does lastIndexOf do?

Tags: javascript, menu

```
window.onload = initAll;

function initAll() {
    var allLinks = document.getElementsByTagName("a");

    for (var i=0; i<allLinks.length; i++) {
        if (allLinks[i].className.indexOf("menuLink") > -1) {
            allLinks[i].onclick = toggleMenu;
        }
    }
}

function toggleMenu() {
    var startMenu = this.href.lastIndexOf("/")+1;
    var stopMenu = this.href.lastIndexOf(".");
    var thisMenuName = this.href.substring(startMenu,stopMenu);

    var thisMenu = document.getElementById(thisMenuName).style;
    if (thisMenu.display == "block")  {
        thisMenu.display = "none";
    }
    else {
        thisMenu.display = "block";
    }

    return false;
}
```

I have two questions

What does `this.href.lastIndexOf("/")+1;` and `this.href.lastIndexOf(".");` do?

Comment: Have a look at [`String.lastIndexOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/lastIndexOf)

Answer (score 3):

the `lastIndexOf` function is used to determine the location of the LAST occurrence of a character (or sub-string) inside a string.

For example:

```
var helloWorldString = "Hello, World";
var firstOccurance = helloWorldString.indexOf('o'); // returns 4
var lastOccurance = helloWorldString.lastIndexOf('o'); // returns 8
```

So in your code, if you have a path "http://www.mywebsite.com/foo/bar.html", your code will do the following:

```
//Find the last "/" character in the URL and adds one to the result.
var startMenu = this.href.lastIndexOf("/") + 1; 

//Find the last "." character in the URL.
var stopMenu = this.href.lastIndexOf("."); 

//get the file name from the URL
var thisMenuName = this.href.substring(startMenu,stopMenu);
```

So given the example URL above, `thisMenuName` would contain "bar".

HTH

Answer (score 2):

lastIndexOf() finds the last occurrence of your string in the string you're searching.

So the first lastIndexOf() finds the last "/" in the href attribute of the link. The second one finds the last occurrence of "." in the href attribute.